# SVG invalid property value in Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, svg

I am changing a background via this css:

```
          background: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
         width="10px" height="11px" viewBox="0 0 10 11" enable-background="new 0 0 10 11" xml:space="preserve">
         <g><g><path fill="#3477d1" d="M3.7,11c-0.3,0-0.6-0.2-0.8-0.4L0.2,6.9C-0.1,6.4,0,5.7,0.4,5.3C0.9,5,1.5,5.1,1.9,5.5L3.6,8l4.4-7.5 C8.4,0,9-0.2,9.5,0.2c0.5,0.3,0.6,1,0.3,1.5l-5.2,8.8C4.4,10.8,4.1,11,3.7,11C3.8,11,3.7,11,3.7,11z"/>
         </g></g></svg>');
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-position: center;
```

and it works in Chrome & Safari, however in firefox I get invalid property value and it fails to load the SVG.

I cant work out which property it is referring to.

Has anyone come across this or can point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

# is a reserved character in a URL as it indicates the start of [a fragment identifier.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier)

You need to URL encode the URL which will mean that the # will become %23